# Al ingresar un valor por pantalla, con C++, no lo calcula y me devuelve lo mismo que ingresé

Tags: c++

Estoy aprendiendo C++ en la universidad y hace ya algunas horas estoy con un problema en el código el cual no logro solucionar. No logro encontrar dónde está fallando mi función porque al ingresar un valor por pantalla no lo calcula y me devuelve lo mismo que ingresé. Les dejo mi código por acá:

```
int num1;
int num2 = 100;
int resultado;
int ganancia = 20;
int iva = 21;

using namespace std; 

int calcularPrecioDeVenta(int preciocompra, int stock)
{

if(stock >= 100 and preciocompra < 1500 ) {
ganancia = 15;
} else if (stock < 50) 
{
ganancia = 15;
} else 
{
return (preciocompra) + (ganancia) + (iva);
}
}

int main() {
cout << "Ingrese el precio de compra:"; 
cin >> num1;
resultado = calcularPrecioDeVenta(num1,num2);
cout << "El resultado es: " << resultado;
cin.get();

}
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problema y solución:

El problema está en la función `calcularPrecioDeVenta`, en esta parte en específico:

```
}else
return (preciocompra) + (ganancia) + (iva);
}
}//Fin de la función;
```

Lo que pasa es que si las condiciones se cumplen:

```
if(stock >= 100 and preciocompra < 1500 ) {
ganancia = 15;
} else if (stock < 50) 
{
ganancia = 15;
}
```

La función retorna el primer parámetro que pasaste, o en otras palabras el segundo elemento en la pila.
Para arreglarlo solo tienes que quitar el `else` final. Así quedaría la función arreglada:

```
int calcularPrecioDeVenta(int preciocompra, int stock)
{

if(stock >= 100 and preciocompra < 1500) {
ganancia = 15;
} else if (stock < 50) 
{
ganancia = 15;
}
//Quité el else.
return (preciocompra) + (ganancia) + (iva);

}
```

### Explicación:

Tu función no retornará el cálculo que quieres porque solo retorna el cálculo si la condición no se cumple, pero ¿por qué me retorna el primer número que pasé como parámetro y no me da error?:

Recuerda que el lenguaje C no se compila directamente, se traduce a ensamblador y después se compila a lenguaje de máquina.

Cuando pasas una variable por parámetro, lo que realmente haces es usar un espacio de memoria apartado para almacenar múltiples valores temporalmente llamado the stack( la pila ), cuando pasas estas dos variable como parámetro:

> Nota: Los comentarios en ensamblador x86 se hacen con este signo `;` pero le agregué `//` para que se note que es un comentario.

```C++
calcularPrecioDeVenta(num1,num2);
```

Lo que realmente haces es:

```Nasm
; Esto es esamblador x86
push [num1];//Insertamos el valor de num1 en la pila.
push [num2];//Insertamos el valor de num2 en la pila.
call calcularPrecioDeVenta;//Llamamos a la funcion.
```

Cuando se llega al final de la función para retornar algo el compilador saca el último elemento que se consigue en la pila y lo inserta en la variable mencionada: `pop resultado;`, pero al no conseguir la declaración `return` la pc saca el último valor insertado en la pila y lo inserta en la variable `resultado`; para evitar eso se modifica el primer valor pasado por la pila y se libera todo lo demás:

```nasm
mov [esp+8],resultado;//Nos movemos por la pila pasando por ip como primer valor y num2 como el segundo hasta llegar al valor num1 y lo modificamos.
return 4;//Liberamos num2 de la pila.
```

```nasm
pop [resultado];//Sacamos el valor de la posicion num1 y la liberamos tambien( add esp,4 )
```

Pero al estar encerrado en un condicional el compilador hace su trampa y libera la posiciones que quiere y no te calcula nada:

```nasm
cmp eax,ebx;//Supondremos que esta == es toda la comparación:
jns true;//Saltamos si es true;
    ;//False:
    mov eax,[preciocompra];//Movemos el valor de preciocompla al registro de 32bits eax.
    mov ebx,[ganancia];// Movemos el valor de ganancia al registro ebx
    add eax,ebx;// eax=eax+ebx
    mov ebx,[iva]
    add eax,ebx;//eax=eax+ebx
    mov [esp+8],eax;//posicion de la pila num1 ahora vale eax.
    return 4;//Liberamos 4 posiciones a la pila y reglesamos el programa a la siguiente instruccion o pop IP y add esp,4;//Nota que el numero cuatro es el mismo que usamos para return.
true:
    mov [ganancia],15
    return 4;
```

Y terminas recibiendo el mismo valor que pasaste: `pop [resultado];//resultado=[esp] y add esp,4`
Sé que el código en ensamblador que te enseñé no está completamente bueno, pero ahí te dejo un concepto pequeño de lo que pasa.

### Recomendaciones:

En vez de usar variables globales puedes ponerlas en `main` y te quedará casi igual (con la excepción de la variable `ganancia` y `iva`). Puedes declararla en la función en que la vas a usar. También recomiendo arreglar la identación porque se te hará más fácil entender dónde empieza y termina cada bloque y también puedes resumir un poco más el `if` en la función `calcularPrecioDeVenta`:

```C++
#include <iostream>


using namespace std; 

int calcularPrecioDeVenta(int preciocompra, int stock)
{
    int ganancia = 20;
    int iva = 21;
    if( ( stock >= 100 and preciocompra < 1500) || stock < 50 ) {
        ganancia = 15;
    }
    return (preciocompra) +  (ganancia) + (iva);
}

int main() {
    int num1;
    int resultado=100;//Nota que no usé la variable num2 porque tu código no la necesita.
    cout << "Ingrese el precio de compra:"; 
    cin >> num1;
    resultado = calcularPrecioDeVenta(num1,resultado);
    cout << "El resultado es: " << resultado;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

### Enlaces:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVG7TsNAEOz9FaPQ2CIEO1IoYicVFDSIin45L9YJ@87cgwbyQdR8Ah8W7uwkOBJXnHSzszNzu6Lvrxoh9vsLqUTra0YltXWGqdsmibdSNVDUse1JMKyrSySJVA6CWuFbMo@GhdS3/MTKURor/YAI3fWG5oiIdVq8ZslHgnAi0JAiJSRhg2VenmD5PiDFAXlJkY692G5Q5DlI1WfyqFCs8jzD5@eBWGGVI8NoFc/EqliNwrvhNuy8UUinehkugfTYEl9pyJSVyW78dEdSpUf1CCjfFX/5DVvfOqr1JoQtr68ftCO8eYbS8PbnCy3hnYyk55Zj6xK9NrHuPMTPdy0bHamBpViwlY4Wg7bQ3qGqMLtXTfBgcHsYA8LCxujrWdjMQJYK2@0k2SlVGMH/W4vc@YmWleemd@1Egu0aswifoPLoumjYpVk5HW7Y7W6/v0l@AQ)

Comment: Genio, me sirvió! Muchas gracias.

Comment: @Natzzuke No soy muy bueno en esamblador, cuando termines de aplender C/C++ te recomiendo aprenderlo( Pero ojo: No intentes aprenderlo antes ). Mejoré un poco mi respuesta, espero que te sirva.